# Get values from a Activity with CheckBoxList to another Activity

Tags: android, android-listview, checkboxlist, android-activity

What I want to do is relatively simple: I have 3 tables on my SQLite database: Filmes (Movies), Genero (Genre) and Filmes_Genero (a table that make a relationship between the tables). So I have a screen with a movie cadastre form and another screen that lists the possible genres for the movie that is called by a button from Cadastre screen. So how can I get the values of checked boxes back to my Cadastre Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start the activity using `startActivityForResult()` on your `Cadastre` activity, and then override the `onActivityResult()` method to read the result data (in a moment). In your checkbox activity, before you call finish(), you must set the extras on the activity result. This [page](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_31.html) has a simple example.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I'll test your sugestion now, then later I'll post my results. For now, thanks.